# Rshiny: I want to allow users to select 3 graphs

Tags: r, plot, rshiny

In my server function, I have a code that is designed to let the user see one of three graphs.

```
x = reactive({
    
    if (input$Option == "By rating"){
      output$Movies = renderPlot({ggplot(data(),aes(`Rate`,`Gross Worldwide`, colour=Company)) +geom_point(size = 2,alpha = 0.6) +
          theme_bw()+geom_text(aes(label=`Original Title`),hjust=0, vjust=0)})
    }
    else if (input$Option == "By Opening Weekend (USA)"){
      output$Movies = renderPlot({ggplot(data(),aes(`Opening Weekend USA`,`Gross Worldwide`, colour=Company))+geom_point(size = 2,alpha = 0.6) +
          theme_bw()+geom_text(aes(label=`Original Title`),hjust=0, vjust=0)})
    }
    else if (input$Option == "By Budget"){
      output$Movies = renderPlot({ggplot(data(),aes(`Budget`,`Gross Worldwide`, colour=Company))+geom_point(size = 2,alpha = 0.6) +
          theme_bw()+geom_text(aes(label=`Original Title`),hjust=0, vjust=0)})
    }
  })
  
 output$Movies = renderPlot(x())
```

In my ui function, I have the selector made that allows them to pick out the different options they wish to use.

```
sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Option", "Options:", 
                choices=c("By rating", "By Opening Weekend (USA)", "By Budget")),
```

The problem I am running into is that while this code nominally works, if I was to actually run it, the selector for the three sorting methods while working, don't actually change the graph. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is your use of renderPlot within the reactive, and then again renderPlot in Output$Movies. Thus, you are saying to renderPlot twice. How I got it to work for me was just removing the Output$Movies  == renderPlot from the reactive, keeping only the renderPlot as the separate function. Since I don't have your data, I changed it up a bit and used mtcars to show a simple working example of how you can use the reactive:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      selectInput("Option", "Options:", 
                  choices=c("By rating", "By Opening Weekend (USA)", "By Budget")),
      plotOutput("Movies")
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      x = reactive({
        
        if (input$Option == "By rating"){
          ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,cyl, colour=gear)) +geom_point(size = 2,alpha = 0.6)
        }
        else if (input$Option == "By Opening Weekend (USA)"){
          ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,disp, colour=vs)) +geom_point(size = 2,alpha = 0.6)
        }
        else if (input$Option == "By Budget"){
          ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,drat, colour=hp)) +geom_point(size = 2,alpha = 0.6)
        }
      })
      
      output$Movies = renderPlot(x())
      
      
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hopefully this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Thank you very much. This has solved my issue!